# Update a field in the last document in Firestore collection Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a field in the last document in the Firestore collection. My updating method is below:

```
updateHours() {
    return usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
        .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
        .limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
          return querySnapshot.docs.map((e) {
        usersRef
            .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
            .doc(e.reference.id)
            .update({"totalTime": FieldValue.increment(1)});
       });
     });
    }
```

This does not work. If I use .forEach(), then all documents get updated. So, how to update only the last document field?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to update the `totalTime` field inside the last document, please use the following lines of code:

```
void updateHours() async{
    CollectionReference postsRef = usersRef
               .doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
               .collection('posts');
    QuerySnapshot query = await postsRef.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
               .limit(1)
               .getDocuments();

    query.documents.forEach((doc) {
        doc.reference.updateData({"totalTime": FieldValue.increment(1)});
    });
}
```

Don't forget that Firebase APIs are asynchronous, and you need to wait for the data until it becomes available.

Comment: thank you, Alex for the response. But I need to update only the last document field. My code works fine with .forEach() method, but it updates the 'totalTime' field in ALL documents.

Comment: The code in my answer will only update the last document in the query. See `limit(1)`? Have you even tried it? Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: yes, i tried it. there is not much difference in our codes. yours also updates all documents...

Comment: Please edit your question and show me the changed code. It should update only the last document since the query is limited to returning only one document. Are you sure the code in your question is commented?

Comment: I did try your code as is. But it updates all the 'totalTime' fields in all the documents in my collection... which is weird, maybe i should raise an issue with the firebase?

Comment: Are you sure you're using `query.documents.forEach((doc)` and **not** `postsRef.documents.forEach((doc)` somehow? Besides that, what is the size of the `query` object before iterating?

Comment: Alex's code is correct for updating one document, as the `query` variable will contain at most one result. However, if the `forEach` loop is making you uncomfortable, you can also do `query.docs[0].reference.updateData(...)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Pointing a document by its index seems much easier. Thank you, puf.

Comment: thank you, both Frank & Alex! After delibiration I decided that updating all is actually better in my case. However, will def need this in the future.