# Flutter: Updating field in the last doc only

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, field

I am facing trouble updating one field in the last Cloud Firestore database doc only. Below code updates the field in all the documents of the collection:

```
removeHours(int i) async {
debugPrint('gtdytdtf ----> $i');
return usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
    .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
    .limit(1).get().then((querySnapshot) {
  return querySnapshot.docs[0].reference
   .update({"totalFastTime": FieldValue.increment(-i)});
});
}
```

So, how do I limit it to the last document's field only? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the problem? Error message?

Comment: no error. It updates the field in all docs. I need to update only the last doc. will try the code below...

Comment: @MyCar, nope. Updated all the docs...

Comment: without the .limit(1)? same thing.... updates all the docs' field... so wierd...

Comment: the code result is the same. it updates EVERY docs' field value. I need to update only the LAST doc's value.

Comment: please check the this stackoverflow answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/71869996/18265638)

Comment: that was my question :D asked few months ago. still not found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
removeHours(int i) async {
  debugPrint('gtdytdtf ----> $i');
  return usersRef.doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid).collection('posts')
    .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) async {
       await querySnapshot.docs.elementAt(querySnapshot.size - 1).reference.update({'totalFastTime': FieldValue.increment(-i)});
  });
}
```

Comment: still the same. it updates every docs' field.... is it possible to achieve it with rules? sooo weird

Comment: :( nooo, still the same!

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you...

Comment: thank you for trying though... Hope google guys will help me!